# Botão direcionar dependendo se o usuário está logado ou não

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Tenho um botão que leva para outra tela, porém caso o usuário não esteja logado no sistema ele deve redirecionar para a tela de login e não para a que já está indo. Tem como fazer isso direto no link_to?

```
li= link_to 'Anuncie', new_subscription_path, class: "button"
```

Comment: Vc está usando o que para autenticar seu usuário? Devise?

Comment: Sim , estou usando o Devise

Answer (score 0):

Fiz do seguinte modo e funcionou

```
li= link_to_if(@current_user.nil?, "Anuncie seu imóvel", new_user_session_path, class: "button") do
      = link_to  'Anuncie seu imóvel' ,new_subscription_path, class: "button"
      end
```

Queria saber se funcionaria um condicional usando o button_to ao invés de link_to